# Trim Intermediate spaces in a string in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

In the result, want only intermediate spaces to be removed.

Need to print only first part before hypen (-) along with Percentages.

Can you please help.

Input String: AMAZON - 25%; SAP - XXXXX - 45%; MICROSOFT - XXX&YYY - 30%

Query:

```
SELECT 
translate(left("S_Name",POSITION(',' IN "S_Name")-1),'(,),{,},"','') as FirstPart,
translate(SUBSTRING ("S_Name",length("S_Name") -4 ,4),'(,),{,},"','')as secondpart;
```

Comment: Try `CASE WHEN THEN` to remove it

Comment: do u need first part and last part of a string? If multiple hypen exists then remove middle part. Right?

Comment: @RahulBiswas : Yes. Even though how many number of hypens are present, need to print only 1st part before 1st hypen and ignore all and print percentage corresponding to it.

Comment: "I want to delete [...] from result."   I do not see `[...]` in your example input data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regexp_split_to_table` can be used to split the value into strings by the delimiter `;`, then you can use `split_part` to get the first and second parts of the desired result.

```
Select trim(split_part(t,' - ',1)) As First,
       trim(reverse(split_part(reverse(t),' - ',1))) As Second
From regexp_split_to_table('SUCCESS FACTORS - 25%; SAP - XXXXX - 45%; MICROSOFT - XXX&YYY - 30%', ';') As t;
```

Data Output:

| first | second |
| --- | --- |
| SUCCESS FACTORS | 25% |
| SAP | 45% |
| MICROSOFT | 30% |

Comment: ? "SUCCESSFACTORS" and not "SUCCESS FACTORS" ?

Comment: @Sai Bharadwaj I noticed you've changed your mind. is there something wrong with the solution?

Comment: @Luuk It was written "Need to print only first part before hypen (-)[Without Spaces]"

Comment: Indeed. so his own solution was only missing 1 space (in te second argument to `TRANSLATE`) ? (for the `firstPart`)

Comment: Loosing a leading space can be done using `LTRIM()`.

Comment: @Sai Bharadwaj This was my initial decision with a space between SUCCESS and FACTORS, after which you commented that it was necessary to remove the space.

Comment: @AntonGrig : Even this works well! just a space on the first word alone. It works! Thanks a lot for help! :)

Comment: @Sai Bharadwaj You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Split the initial string by `;` into a 'table' and then use regular expressions to extract the needed parts into columns.

```sql
select 
    trim(substring(s from '^([\w ]+)')) "first",
    substring(s from '([\d]+%)$') "second"
from unnest(string_to_array('SUCCESS FACTORS - 25%; SAP - XXXXX - 45%; MICROSOFT - XXX&YYY - 30%', ';')) s;
```

| first | second |
| --- | --- |
| SUCCESS FACTORS | 25% |
| SAP | 45% |
| MICROSOFT | 30% |